# cannot Connect to online Mysql Database (c#)

Tags: c#, mysql, database

My MYsql database is on "https://www.lima-city.de/" when i try to connect to it :

```
 private string mysqlConnectionString = "Server= 10.246.16.74:3306; Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=myname;Pwd=pwd;";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(mysqlConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
```

i get   -> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
but why?

Comment: Did you set the proper network authorizations? Firewalls?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the blanks from your connection string.

Comment: In case you try to connect from a different domain , check that you have allowed remote MySQL from from hosting provider control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your connection string

```
private string mysqlConnectionString = "Server=10.246.16.74;Port=3306;Database=test;
User=myname;Password=pwd;Option=3";
```

I have removed the port number from the server address.

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: keyword not supportet "option"

Comment: Try using without option, I have removed port from server ip address. also  port argument is not required too because, default port is 3306 for mysql so it should work without it.

final string should be something like 


**private string mysqlConnectionString = "Server=10.246.16.74;Database=test;
User=myname;Password=pwd;";**

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=My_Mysql_Database;Uid=root;Pwd=root;"